# facebook graph api, fields are empty or disallowed by Access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I was trying out the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=694736855?fields=interests,interested_in), I wanted to get myself's interests. I couldn't get the data for the fields "interests" or "interested_in". There are 2 things related which I confirm all set:

1) I allowed everything on the Access Token dialog.

2) I did add interests to my Facebook profile, I could view them there.

What else should I check? Tks

Updated: by "interests" I mean the interests that I added on my profile, see attached photo[image]

(Off topic: I believe this is a bug, but their bug report page ...has a bug, which doesn't let me report it, keep asking me to input the field "Apps", which I tried: Open Graph, Graph API, ...)

Comment: You sure you have checked the `user_interests` permission? coz, I'm getting the interest list with my id.

Comment: @Shadowfax like I said, I checked ALL permissions, including user_interests